# Qt5 and Pattern for similar dialogs implementation

Tags: c++, qt, oop, design-patterns, ooad

What is in your opinion the best way to implement similar dialogs in Qt5 without duplicating the code?

This is the problem: having two "slightly different" data structures, with many common parts, implement two "slightly different" QDialog to handle the user interaction.

We have two structures:

```
class DataA {
public:
  int one, two, three;
  bool x,y;
  SubdataA subA;
}

class DataB {
public:
  int one, two, three;
  bool x,y;
  SubdataB subB;
}
```

SubdataX is some other structured data we need to handle in the GUI. The two QDialog should handle the common fields the same way, while SubdataX must be handled by specific parts. The code should also make some operation on the data structures, and provide output files. This part is quite easy.

My question is, what are the best strategies to implement this? The objective is to have elegant code that should be quite easy to maintain and as most readable as possible. The framework is Qt, so the solution should be tailored to Qt with qdialog layout in UI files, since the gui layout is too complex to design it by code.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you use polymorphism?

Comment: This was my first thought, but I find difficult to manage the ancestor class, (that should be abstract) and the ui files. But this can be a solution. Other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Tyler Jandreau stated, a possible solution is to use polymorphism.

But this requires a careful planning of architecture and class  inheritance, because to avoid using downcasting and a huge and unmaintenable number of switch() cases, you need also to use polymorphism on the GUI classes.

As View/Model architecture requires, the data classes will be mimicked by the control/Gui classes.

Data classes will be implemented using an ancestor, abstract class `CommonData` that includes the common "fields", and two (or more) concrete data classes derived from `CommonData` through inheritance. My first idea was to use composition instead, but this would pose other issues when implementing the gui.

So `DataA` and `DataB` are derived from `CommonData`.

On the Gui side, the structure is similar, but due to lack of inheritance support of the UI form classes generated by Qt's `uic`, we cannot use inheritance. My first guess was to use Template Metaprogramming, and implement the ancestor class as a Template class, but though it worked on the C++ side, `moc` refuses to parse that class and generate the `moc_X` file when the `Q_OBJECT` tagged class is a template.

So we are going to use a mix of inheritance and composition.

This is the architecture: a "container" GUI class (`ContainerDialog`) implements the GUI for the `CommonData` class; a `PluggableInterface` abstract class will define a set of operation (we'll see which below); a set of concrete classes derived from the latter will implement the GUI logic for the remaining classes.

So the `ContainerDialog` loads a `ContainerDialog.ui` form as a "standard"  QDialog, and manages all the interface with `CommonData`. His constructor , or a setter will receive a `CommonData` pointer, remember that `CommonData` is abstract and cannot be instantiated.

The specific fields are managed thorugh specific graphic components that are "plugged" in the ContainerDialog gui. For example, a method defined in `PluggableInterface` will insert the QWidget derived component in the ContainerDialog gui. The classes involved are, for example, `ComponentA1`, `ComponentA2`, `ComponentB`, etc...

The use of the abstract interface `PluggableInterface` and the UI components will prevent the `ContainerDialog` to know what kind of concrete class are in use, and all the necessary code to instantiate the specific classes can be implemented using some creational pattern (Abstract Factory, Prototypes, etc...)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "difficult to manage the ancestor class". I think I understand you want a polymorphic input to determine the layout of a dialog box. Is this assumption correct?

For example, given the following classes, you're able to use a dynamic cast to influence the behaviour of a dialog box.

```
class IData {
public;
    int one, two, three;
    bool x, y;
};

class DataA : public IData {
public:
    // more data in here
};

class DataB : public IData {
public:
     // more unique data in here
}
```

Now, assume you have written a dialog box with a function signature

```
void configureDialog(IData *data) {
    DataA *dataA = dynamic_cast<DataA*>(data);
    if (dataA) {
        // configure what parts of the QDialog to see here
    }

    DataB *dataB = dynamic_cast<DataB*>(data);
    if (dataB) {
        // configure other parts of the QDialog you want to see
    }
}
```

Which would allow for polymorphic configuration of a single `QDialog` box.

Comment: This may be acceptable for the data structure (though I don't like too much using dynamic_cast, but this can be worked around). But for QDialog this is a problem, unless we use a "big do-all" class that implements the logic for all types of structures. A better OOP approach would be preferred, so using polymorphism also on dialogs. The problem is with the ui file processing is implemented in Qt. As explained here: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/designer-using-a-ui-file.html we must parse the UI file when building. But the ui_xxx class is generated and cannot be subclassed :-(

Comment: I am still failing to see the problem. Just use multiple inheritance using the class defined by the UI file for each unique data item.

Comment: let me restate:
DialogA class use dialogA.ui that generates the class ui_dialogA. DialogB class has similar companions. The idea is to reuse much of code, but ui files and classes cannot be used polymorphically. So what is the architecture you are suggesting?
Thanks.

Comment: "... but ui files and classes cannot be used polymorphically." is a statement I believe to be incorrect. Please review http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/uitools-multipleinheritance.html

Comment: Tyler, thanks for your patience, but can you elaborate this? How would you structure the inheritance tree in my example? Thank you for your help.

Comment: No worries, that's why I decided to answer this question. I would probably make a basic form with the UI designer that covered most of your interactions (save, load, ok, stuff like that). Keep in mind that layouts can be changed and widgets added/subtracted via code. I would then add/remove widgets for that particular DataA or DataB QDialog by inheriting the base class form defined by the UI. For a purely abstract interpretation using UI designer, I don't think you have the option. UI designer is a good tool but lacks the flexibility required for your application.

Comment: mmm... thanks. That's a solution. On the other hand, I was thinking that we may workaround the impossibility of using inheritance with UI_xxx classes, by using template metaprogramming. I need to try it, I'll share the solution here if it works.